# What's the meaning of "out" in "build out"?

Tags: phrases

From [NPR](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=280255216)

> Critics suggest these big ISPs aren't ***building out*** their networks enough to keep pace with the huge growth in demand.

I haven't found the definition of "build out" in the dictionary, so I looked "out" up, and find the following definition:

> out: used to say that something is done carefully or completely

And examples about the usage:

> I spent all morning cleaning out the kitchen cupboards.
>
> In the summer months the soil dries out quickly.

I want to know if "out" fit in with the definition. And I guess "build out" means "build carefully and completely", doesn't it? Because I have encountered the expression twice, I want to know the exact meaning, but I cannot find it on the Internet or dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an interesting phrase.

"Building out" in this sense probably means growing, spreading out.

> And I guess "build out" means "build carefully and completely", doesn't it?

I don't think so, although it *could*. Given the context, it sounds like internet providers are trying to expand their properties to compete, and not necessarily to finish a specific project or directive. It just looks like a conjoining of "building" and "spreading out". If I were talking about a project, although it would sound extremely unusual, I could say "We're about to build out that particular phase", and the person I was talking to could probably get the idea, although I would much more likely say "We're about to finish out that particular phase" or "complete".

Comment: I agree with your premise about "building out" ≈ "spreading out". As I analyzed the question, the word "sprawling" came to mind.

Comment: Yes, "outward" -- expansion -- is the implication. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/buildout

Comment: @J.R. I think there's a tinge of [“fill out”](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+"fill+out") in there as well. When I have heard “build out”, it has indicated that a nascent structure or system would be developed to completion. Spatial expansion is not necessarily implied. I think the OP actually has a good sense of the word, especially “build [. . .] **completely**.”

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this phrase quite a bit in the tech sphere, where it indicates that an undeveloped project will be taken from [ideation to implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_thinking#Design_thinking_as_a_process_for_problem-solving).

Similar to [“filling out”](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22fill+out%22), “building out” can certainly involve physical expansion, but can also be used more abstractly to indicate that something will be [solidified](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+solidified), [realized (sense 3)](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+realized), or generally [developed](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22develop%22)—usually *completely,* as you surmised.